# Paypal integration for multiple users to receive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement Paypal in one of my project where the organisation registered in my project will connect their paypal account and receive payments from their clients.

I really want to know how can I implement the same for multiple users

**Here's what I want to do with it,**

**1. I have a project where schools have their account and the school manages all the students from the web panel**

**2. I want to give an option to the students to pay to the school for appointments**

**3. Here I was trying to give an option to the school to connect their Paypal account with the panel**

**4. and students of that particular school will pay the school directly from web panel itself which should be credited to the schools Paypal account**

**Thanks & Regards**

Comment: Unclear what this question is about, but perhaps https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thank you for responding to the question
I have updated the question with the scenario what I am trying to achieve with it. please check and try to help me out with it Thanks

Comment: You seem to be describing a normal PayPal Checkout button with a `payee` that is the school's PayPal account. See the above link

Comment: Even though it is a normal paypal checkout how am I supposed to store the Paypal account information for multiple schools in my project ?

Comment: A database table of schools and their accounts, perhaps

Comment: Sure, Thanks @PrestonPHX this could be another possible solution for me to implement the same.

I was actually thinking what way the appointment scheduling software "Acuity" might have implemented Paypal in their system